# Cypher - matching two different possible paths and return both

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a a data set that I have represented here as an example:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=3dq78v

What I am trying to do is for every Z node in my graph (the example only has one but I have many) I want to capture a set of properties that cover all all of the associated A, B, C and D nodes and relationships.

I have come across two issues trying to do this. The first is that the C nodes are either connected to the to the B nodes OR the A nodes. Second the D nodes are connected to C nodes but not always present.

I am looking to output a table that looks something like this:

> Z.prop | A.prop | B.prop | (A-B rel).prop | c.prop | (c-d rel).prop | d.prop

I have tried a lot of combinations of using OPTIONAL MATCH and using WITH but I can not get it. Everything I have tried with OPTIONAL MATCH will find that match if it exists and then not allow me to maintain the items that did not match this optional match (Which I realize is what it is supposed to do). I can share more specific queries I have tried if that will help.

Any insight would be great!

Edit: using version Neo4j 2.0.3
Edit: updated console link with a small correction

Here is a query I have tried. I realize why this doesn't work, but maybe you can see my 'logic' I want the optional match to not remove nodes if they dont match if it finds some matches. I want the ones that dont match and do.

```
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:has*1..2]->(c:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:has]->(b:B)-[:CONTAINS]->(c)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[cd:knows]->(d:D)
RETURN z.name, a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name, cd.score;
```

EDIT: What I am trying to do is use the results from the 4 queries below but get the results with 1 query

```
#1
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
MATCH (A)-[mr:has]->(b:B)-[:has]->(c:C)
MATCH (c)-[ds:knows]->(d:d)
RETURN  a.name, b.name, mr.order, c.name, d.name, ds.score;

#2
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
MATCH (A)-[mr:has]->(b:B)-[:has]->(c:C)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:knows]->(:d)
RETURN a.name, mr.order, b.name, c.name;

#3
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
MATCH (A)-[:has]->(c:C)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:knows]->(:d)
RETURN  a.name, c.name;

#4
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
MATCH (A)-[:has]->(c:C)
MATCH (c)-[ds:knows]->(d:d)
RETURN a.name, c.name, d.name, ds.score;
```

These don't work the way I was expecting though because some results. For example I was expecting query 3 to only return:

```
A2  C4  d4  8
A2  C4  d5  6
A2  C4  d6  9
```

EDIT - EXACT output I am aiming for:

```
a.name  mr.order b.name c.name  d.name  d.score
A1      1        B3
A1      2        B1     C2
A1      2        B1     C5
A1      2        B1     C1      d1      1
A1      2        B1     C1      d3      4
A1      2        B1     C1      d2      3
A2      1        B4
A2      2        B2     C3
A2                      C4      d4      8
A2                      C4      d5      6
A2                      C4      d6      9
```

This matches 9 of the 11 lines I am looking for, it misses the lines with B3 and B4

```
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
WITH a, z
MATCH (a)-[*1..2]-(c:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[mr:has]->(b:B)-[:has]-(c:C)
WITH a, b, c, z, mr
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[cd:knows]->(d:d)
RETURN z.name, a.name, mr.order, b.name, c.name, d.name, cd.score;
```

Comment: You really need to share your queries; it's not at all clear what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: I have added some queries that I have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely sure about what you would expect as the ouput, but this one might work:

```
MATCH (z:Z)-[:has]->(a:A)
WITH a, z
MATCH (b:B), (a)-[*1..2]-(c:C)
WHERE (a)-[:has]->(b)-[:CONTAINS]->(c) OR (a)-[:has*1..2]->(c)
WITH a, b, c, z
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[cd:knows]->(d:d)
RETURN z.name, a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name, cd.score;
```

From there you could optimize it.

**Edit**
After your adding, I think that the only one to achieve that is by using a `UNION` of two queries

```
MATCH (a:A)-[mr:has]->(b:B)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-->(c:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[cd]->(d:d)
RETURN a.name, mr.order, b.name, c.name, d.name, cd.score
UNION
MATCH (a:A)-[mr:has]->(c:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:C)-[cd]->(d:d)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B)-->(c:C)
RETURN a.name, mr.order, b.name, c.name, d.name, cd.score
```

Note that in the second query after the `UNION`, the `OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B)-->(c:C)` is only there to make the `UNION` possible, since Neo4j doesn't allow to just return an empty string instead of `b.name`. The good news is that `UNION` will remove duplicates, therefore resulting in the expected result.

```
a.name  mr.order    b.name  c.name  d.name  cd.score
A1      1           B3          
A1      2           B1      C5      
A1      2           B1      C1      d1      1
A1      2           B1      C1      d2      4
A1      2           B1      C1      d3      3
A1      2           B1      C2      
A2      1           B4          
A2      2           B2      C3      
A2                          C4      d4      8
A2                          C4      d5      6
A2                          C4      d6      9
Showing 1 to 11 of 11 entries
```

Query took 9 ms and returned 11 rows.

Comment: I updated the console, I realized I also need to capture a property from the incoming relationship to (B). And with this I can't add an identifier in the WHERE clause. Thank you!